# IAP Restoration

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift, in-app-purchase

I got a problem working on with restoration of purchased product. Every time user clicks on Restore Button the unlock content works before checking if user is logged in, had he purchased it or not. It just unlocks. So here is my question: How do it right? I Add the code with restoration function and purchase one. Btw purchasing works perfect.

```
 func restorePurchases(){
      println("hello")
      SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
      SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions()
 }

 func buyProduct(){
      SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
      let payment:SKPayment = SKPayment(product: product)
      SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(payment)
 }

 func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError error: NSError!) {
      showAlert("error", message: "hoho")
 }

 func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, updatedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!) {
      for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
           if let trans:SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as? SKPaymentTransaction{
                switch trans.transactionState{
                case .Purchased:
                     self.removeAds()
                     SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                     break
                case .Failed:
                     showAlert("Error", message: "Transaction problem")
                     SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                     break
                case .Restored:
                     self.removeAds()
                     break
                default:
                     break
                }
           }
      }
 }
```

Comment: Is your code reaching the .Restored case? Are you testing in sandbox mode with a user who has not purchased your unlock before?

Comment: @BenFlynn Yes, i tested it with 2 accounts: 1 that have purchased it and 2 who did buy nothing. So i got solution, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer!
The main problem was that I didnt finish transaction in .Restored, so i got the same thing for .Purchased and .Restored.

```
     func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, updatedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!) {
      for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
           if let trans:SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as? SKPaymentTransaction{
                switch trans.transactionState{
                case .Purchased, .Restored:
                     self.removeAds()
                     SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                     break
                case .Failed:
                     showAlert("Error", message: "Transaction problem")
                     SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                     break
                default:
                     break
                }
           }
      }
 }
```

Next - i didnt check can customer make purchases or not. But before this i made the observer:

```
     func restorePurchases(){
      SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
      if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments(){
           SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions()
      }
 }
```

So, that was easy :D
Thanks everyone!